# how to increment matrix element in tensorflow using tf.scatter_add?

Tags: python, tensorflow

tf.scatter_add works nicely for 1d (shape [1](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#scatter_add)) tensors:

```
> S = tf.Variable(tf.constant([1,2,3,4]))
> sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
> sess.run(tf.scatter_add(S, [0], [10]))

array([11,  2,  3,  4], dtype=int32)

> sess.run(tf.scatter_add(S, [0, 1], [10, 100]))

array([ 21, 102,   3,   4], dtype=int32)
```

But how can I increment, say [0,0] element of

```
M = tf.Variable(tf.constant([[1,2], [3,4]]))
```

to make it [[2, 2], [3, 4]]
using tf.scatter_add?

the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#scatter_add) is kind'a cryptic. And I tried different arg values, say

```
> sess.run(tf.scatter_add(M, [[0, 0]], [1]))
*** ValueError: Shapes (1,) and (1, 2, 2) are not compatible
```

and haven't succeeded.

Btw, in my case, M is quite large and is resized dynamically.
So adding zero-but-one equal to 1 element matrix to M is not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tf.scatter_add` updates slices of a tensor and not capable of updating individual coefficients. For instance, it can update entire rows of a matrix at once.

Also, the shape of the `updates` argument to `tf.scatter_add` depends on the shape of its `indices` argument. When the `ref` argument is a matrix with shape `(M, N)`, then

- If `indices` is a scalar `i`, then `updates` should be a vector with shape `(N)`.
- If `indices` is a vector `[i1, i2, .. ik]` with shape `(k)`, then `updates` should have the shape `(k, N)`.

In your case, you can simply add `[1, 0]` to the first row of `M` as follows to get the effect you want:

```
sess.run(tf.scatter_add(M, 0, [1, 0]))
array([[2, 2],
   [3, 4]], dtype=int32)
```